# Are there any examples of PyParsing which add types to output as well as structured tokenization?

Tags: parsing, grammar, pyparsing

All the PyParsing examples I've seen end of up producing a structured nested list of tokens like this :

```
["eat",["stolen","food"]]
```

etc.

I can't seem to find an example that would tag these outputs with types to give me something like :

```
[{"type":"verb","value":"eat"},[{"type":"adj","value":"stolen"},{"type":"noun","value":"food"}]]
```

Can PyParsing do this? (Even if the format is different.) And, if so, can anyone point me to an example?

cheers

Phil

Answer (score 3):

See “[How to structure the returned ParseResults](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/structuring-results.html)” in the [PyParsing quick reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/index.html).

Comment: Although that page doesn't immediately seem to have what I'm looking for :-(